# Cannot call form submit method from template in Angular

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have loaded a form from conditional templateurl and now I cannot call any function on Submit.
If I put this piece of html code directly into my page it works but not when dynamically inserted.
The controller is set globally for the page in the body tag
Any idea on how to sort out this thing?

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="message.send_message()">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="message_title">Title</label>
    <input ng-model="message.message_title" type="text" class="form-control  col-xs-3" " name="message_title" id="message_title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="message_body">Body</label>
    <textarea ng-model="message.message_body" rows="" rows="5" class="form-control col-xs-3" name="message_body" id="message_body"></textarea>
</div>
<input ng-model="message.message_event_id" type="hidden" id="message_event_id" name="message_event_id" value="{{event.event_id}}">
<button ng-click="message.send_message()"  type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin: 1em 25% 1em 25%">New Message</button>
</form>

 $scope.message = {};
     // send message function
     $scope.message.send_message = function (message) {
         console.log("send_message called");
         var result = {};
         result = angular.copy(message);
         console.dir(result);
     }
```

Comment: Can you create a plunkr?

Comment: Your button should be type="submit" and remove the ng-click

Comment: here we go http://plnkr.co/edit/zijm24?p=preview

Comment: nope @JonSamwell does not work either

Answer (score 0):

When you declaring in your directive

```
 scope: {
           isOk: '@'
        },
```

You are isolating the directive's scope from the controller's scope. this is why your `ng-click="send_message(bodymessage)"` didn't work (it searched for `send_message` in the directive scope)

if you would like to share the controller's scope with your directive, remove  `scope: { ... }` from your directive and create `isOk` in the controller's scope

example:

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/inBM7g?p=preview)</kbd>

**#** Note that in many cases it is recommended to separate the directive's scope from the controller's scope

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your directive re-usable you can keep the isolated scope and use the `&` binding, which creates a helper function to call a function on the outer scope ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/oHrAjIOmNZjy31X6TRQ4)):

**Html:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="DirectiveTemplate.html">
  <input ng-model="directiveText">
  <p>You entered {{directiveText}}</p>
  <button ng-click="buttonClicked()">Do It</button>
  <button ng-click="mySubmit({directiveMessage: directiveText})">Another Way</button>
</script>

<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<my-directive my-submit="sendMessage(directiveMessage)"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        mySubmit: '&',
      },
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'DirectiveTemplate.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.buttonClicked = function() {
          scope.mySubmit({directiveMessage: scope.directiveText});
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sendMessage = function(message) {
      alert(message);
    }
  })
```

`directiveText` is a property on the isolated scope.  Angular creates the `mySubmit` helper function on the isolated scope.  It will all a function put into the `my-submit` attribute on your directive element much like `ng-click` does.  You can pass named parameters such as `directiveMessage` by passing an object to that function with those parameters as properties on the object.  I've kept the names different here so you can see as the value of `directiveText` passes through `directiveMessage` for the binding to `message` in the function that is eventually called.